# Socks proxy in tornado AsyncHttpClient

Tags: python, tornado

How can I use socks proxy in tornado AsyncHttpClient?
I found it possible to use only HTTP Proxy without changing the lib...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation, proxy support is only available for the `libcurl` implementation of `AsyncHTTPClient`.

If you will take a deeper look at the `HTTPRequest` object you're passing to the `fetch()` method, you'll notice there's an extra `prepare_curl_callback` argument, which can call `setopt` on the `PyCurl` object before the request is sent.

Here's a little example of such `prepare_curl_callback` function:

```
import pycurl

def prepare_curl_socks5(curl):
    curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
```

And a full usage example:

```
import tornado
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
import tornado.httpclient
import pycurl

def prepare_curl_socks5(curl):
    curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def main():
    # set CurlAsyncHTTPClient the default AsyncHTTPClient
    tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
        "tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")

    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(
        "http://jsonip.com",
        prepare_curl_callback=prepare_curl_socks5,
        proxy_host="localhost",
        proxy_port=9050
    )
    response = yield http_client.fetch(http_request)

    print response.body

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

The additional keyword argument `prepare_curl_callback=prepare_curl_socks5` to the `fetch()` call does the magic, making CURL use SOCKS5 proxy instead of the default - HTTP proxy.